# Unity Coroutine работает с разной скоростью

Tags: unity3d

Я сделал корутину для плавного отображения canvas group и на пк работает норм, но если проверять на макбуке, то скорость (не производительность!!!) именно скорость очень сильно ниже, не i+=.01f, а где-то i+=.0001f, ну очень медленно, на пк после срабатывания корутины, окно появляется в одну секунду, на маке нужно ждать 7сек. Как это исправить?

```
for (float i = cg.alpha; i <= 1.1f; i+=.01f)
    {
        cg.alpha = i;
        yield return null;
    }
```

Comment: *"сделал корутину"* - *"для плавного отображения"* - не видно связи

Comment: А я невижу "пьавности". Грубый turn base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по предоставленному коду, у вас корутина в анимации зависит от времени, а не от количества итераций. Это зачит, что количество итераций (ваше i+=.01f) на всех устройствах будет одинаковое. Другой вопрос, что вы делаете `yield return null`, что значит, что каждый шаг анимации происходит 1 раз за 1 кадр. Чем ниже частота кадров (fps) тем дольше по времени будет выполняться ваша анимация. В таком варианте, как у вас нельзя рассчитывать на то, что на разных устройствах с разной производительностью время этой анимации будет одинаковым.

Теперь практичный совет - ваше решение, своего рода изобретение велосипеда, на отладку которого вы тратите много времени. Чтобы этого избежать используйте [DoTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676?aid=1100l355n&gclid=Cj0KCQiA5bz-BRD-ARIsABjT4nhufp552MgEhKiFf8Q7P5DGCeJBDcScLojvqOmzd8nz46PZxmqdAtIaAuGDEALw_wcB&pubref=UnityAssets%2ADyn09%2A1723478829%2A67594162255%2A336275757769%2Ag%2A%2A%2Ab%2Ac%2Agclid%3DCj0KCQiA5bz-BRD-ARIsABjT4nhufp552MgEhKiFf8Q7P5DGCeJBDcScLojvqOmzd8nz46PZxmqdAtIaAuGDEALw_wcB&utm_source=aff), даже его бесплатной версии хватит на все ваши нужны с лихвой. К тому же он позволяет делать анимации по времени, а не по кадрам. В вашем случае можно воспользоваться `DoTween.DoFade()`, например  :

```
sequence = DOTween.Sequence();
sequence.Append(myObject.DOFade(1.0f, 0.2f));
sequence.Play();
```

где myObject какой-то ваш объект, а параметры - целевое значение и время, за которое оно должно быть достигнуто.